# jQuery basic ajax GET + php return

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

EDIT: fixed _ typo (2x), added header, still logging 100.

Upon clicking a button in my JavaScript, I'm firing this function (parameter: 100)

```
ajaxManager = new AjaxManager();
ajaxManager.requestHexContent(100);

function AjaxManager (){
    this.requestHexContent = function(id){
        $.ajax({
            type : 'get',
            url : 'simulator/hexFiller.php',
            dataType : 'json',
            data: {
                gameid: id,
            },
            success : function(ret){
                console.log(ret);
            },
            error : function(){
                alert("error")
            }
        });
    },
}
```

this is my hexFiller.php

```
<?php   
header('Content-Type: application/json');

  $ret; 

  if (isset($_GET["gameid"])){
    if ($_GET["gameid"] == 100){
        $ret = 200;
    }
   else {
    $ret = "error";
 }
}

echo json_encode($ret);

?>
```

Now, what i would expect to happen is for my browser to log "200" to the console, or, "error".
Instead it logs "100" to the console.

Can someone explain to me the fundamental error in my thinking?

Comment: How are you calling the function? Can we have the code when you fire this function upon clicking?

Comment: edited the code, also added in the call of requestHexContent()

Comment: Its working perfectly fine here. Earlier it was coming under error and alerted "error". When I changed $GET into $_GET. It returned 200.
Anything else you wanted? Shall I paste the code?

Comment: mh. Perhaps something different is wrong with secureWAMP then.
thanks for investigating.

Comment: as with @AshishChoudhary , my test logged 200

Comment: Im a retard. I edited hexfiller.php in my sublime, but it was actually a different hexfiller.php than the one i thought i was editing. So my original hexfiller.php had still wrong code.

Comment: This happens so often to me as well. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comment, working code is mentioned below:
I only replaced $GET with $_GET.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function AjaxManager() {
        this.requestHexContent = function (id) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: 'simulator/hexFiller.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    gameid: id,
                },
                success: function (ret) {
                    console.log(ret);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("error")
                }
            });
        }
    }

    ajaxManager = new AjaxManager();
    ajaxManager.requestHexContent(100);
</script>
```

hexFiller.php

```
<?php
$ret;

if (isset($_GET["gameid"])) {
    if ($_GET["gameid"] == 100) {
        $ret = 200;
    } else {
        $ret = "error";
    }
}

echo json_encode($ret);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a slight error in your PHP code. You're trying to use $GET[] to get parameters passed to the PHP script. But, it's $_GET[] that you need to use. See http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php.

Comment: But why does it log `100`?

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning a json element from your PHP file.

Add `header('Content-Type: application/json');` at the top of your PHP file.

Also your `$_GET` declaration is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Why it is returning 100, I don't really know, probably an error number. But your PHP code is wrong, it's $_GET not $GET.